# Custom Theme in Drupal Omega

Tags: drupal-7

I am new in drual custom theme designing. I am using Omega theme as bae theme and i created sub theme. I know how to add region and zone. But i am not getting any tutorial how change layout. I enabled custom theme and its showing grid system as front page. I want my custom front page. Any solution or tutorial for creating theme using subtheme.

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning about Omega theme and I have found several free tutorials on this topic. 
I recommend http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Iob6XLRBdQ&feature=share&list=PL15BE2E8313A4E809
to get going :)
enjoy!

Comment: Please note that link-only answers are not encouraged!